# Mapstruct: HashMap<String, Object> as source to Object

Tags: object, hashmap, mapstruct

How could I use a HashMap<String, MyObjectSource> as source to an object?

Here is my target object:

```
public class QuantityDTO{
    private Integer shoes;
    private Integer pants;
}
```

Here is my object source:

```
public class Product{
    private String name;
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

Here is my map<String, Product> :
`<("shoes", Product), ("pants", Product)>`

I've tried to use this approach, but it's failing for me.

My Mapper:

```
@Mapping(target = "shoes", source = "shoes.quantity")
    @Mapping(target = "pants", source = "pants.quantity")
    QuantityDTO mapToQuantityDto(Map<String, Product> map);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Map to Bean mappings` and `nested source mappings` do not combine that well. The problem with this is that MapStruct can not know whether the `.` is meant as a `nested` mapping identifier or if it is part of the `key` for the map itself. Both options are valid.

[The behaviour to allow '.' as part of the key is listed here as a bug.](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/3066)

My suggestion would be to write out the mapping yourself with something like:

```java
    @Mapping(target = "shoes", source = "shoes")
    @Mapping(target = "pants", source = "pants")
    QuantityDTO mapToQuantityDto(Map<String, Product> map);

    default Integer ProductToQuantity(Product product){
        return product == null ? null : product.getQuantity();
    }
```

This way the source field only contains the key, and the rest of the mapping is done at the default method.

For more complex mappings you could add another mapping annotated method to handle the complexity.

Also it would be useful to know what the message is that you get as a reason for it failing, or if you do not get a message what the mapstruct generated code looks like.